# Have kafkacat produce both name of a file and its contents

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

I want `kafkacat` to write both the name of a file and its contents in a single `bash` command, if possible. The following apparently does not work. What am I missing?

```
kafkacat -T -P -b ... -t ... <(echo $file) $file
```

Comment: If you could explain what should happen in your code, create a file or use the content of a file, instead of showing code that is not working as intended or it has different function than what you expected/intended that would be fine

Comment: @Jetchisel Well, I want `kafkacat` to write both the name of a file and its content to the indicated topic. All in one call, if that's possible.

Comment: Ok, so to print the filename and it's content one per line, `awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' file.txt` to print the filename at the top of it's content `awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME} 1' file.txt ` So how would the output of filename and it's content be formatted, and how is the content of the file structured, In one line or new line delimited?

Comment: The approach with `awk 'BEGINFILE ...` is interesting. Will try that. It is a JSON file.

Comment: Overall, you'll need to quote the record value on the CLI. As written, those are interpreted as two arguments